# MomentJS - how to determine if current locale uses AM/PM

Tags: momentjs

I'm using `Ant Design` `Timepicker` to set event times (which are `moment` objects) and to display it correctly I need to determine whether current locale uses AM/PM or 24-hours time format.

Now my functions are using `moment.localeData().longDateFormat('LT')` to display just the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's a pretty straightforward solution:

```
export const use12Hours = ():boolean => {
  const LTformat = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('LT');
  if(LTformat.split(' ').length > 1 && LTformat.split(' ').pop() === 'A') {
    return true;
  } 
  return false;
}
```

Let me know, if there's something to be impoved.